# Set language / locale globally for a Lightning Application

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, locale

Our customers send Quotes to various locales/languages, and need to see the quote *in the recipient's locale*.

In Visualforce I can set a locale/language specifically by using

```
<apex:page language="en-us">
My glorious page content
</apex:page>
```

This solved our issues in Visualforce.

In Lightning, I know I can set a locale related attribute on certain lightning components (e.g [`ui:outputdate`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_outputDate.htm)). I have not found any way to set the language/locale for the whole App.

If there is no native way, does anybody know a Locker friendly JS Library that could assist us here?

Comment: indeed a needed feature in lightning!!!